# Why i can't see the router configuration web page?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

my ISP is BSNL, i use wireless usb modem they provided. No question or problem related internet connection, it is working fine, i just want to open the router configuration page so that i can do some port forwarding. Below is the copy paste from my cmd about default gateway.

```
Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter #4 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:75fe:fa4a::75fe:fa4a(Preferred) 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301 2002:c058:6301::1 
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Now i'm try to open the router configuration page on the web using 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301 and also 2002:c058:6301::1 in google , but it is just showing some search results. How do i see that router configuration page where you need to put username and password ?

edit:
i think i was looking at wrong section, as i'm using usb and there in only one section related usb so i'm copy pasting the information here

```
PPP adapter USBDEVICE:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : USBDEVICE
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 117.254.250.74(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 172.18.3.3
   Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 172.18.3.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

From this information how do i access router configuration page ? i tried 0.0.0.0 , no use, sorry i'm absolute noob on these things

Comment: Chances are your router isn't using ipv6. You're looking at the wrong adaptor

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all of the output from `ipconfig`

Comment: @DavidPostill i just added information of a new section, if you need all the information from ipconfig /all , please tell me

Comment: Agreed with the above. You are looking at a tunnel adapter settings instead of the actual interface.

Comment: What is the name and model number of your "wireless usb modem"?

Comment: @DavidPostill name is BSNL EVDO Rev A USB Data Card , Model : UE100

Comment: @DavidPostill just posting another section , thought it might help `Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Q8ASBLD4HOGK5
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No`

Comment: It not a router it is a modem without any router functionality. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want to open the router configuration page so that I can do some port forwarding

Your Wireless USB Modem (BSNL EVDO Rev A USB Data Card, Model : UE100) does not have any router functionality, according to the [UE100 User Manual](http://www.prithvisolutions.com/Downloads/EvDO%20Data%20Card%20UE100_English%20Manual%20.pdf).

You will **not**, therefore, be able to do any port forwarding.

Speak to your ISP about other possible options.